# Why am I getting a seg fault while calling strtok_r?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, token, strtok

So, I am getting a seg fault whenever I try to call strtok_r, however I am not completely sure why. I am getting this error within this block of code.

I know my error is coming from this section of code, because if I were to take out this while loop, and replace with simply just a printf(str); I get no errors and it prints correctly.

Below is my method containing strtok_r:

```
void parseCommand(char *str)
{
  char *curr;
  char *temp = str;
  char **args=NULL;

  int i = 0;
  curr=strtok_r(temp, " ", &temp);
  while(curr!=NULL){
    args[i]=curr;
    curr=strtok_r(NULL," ",&temp);
    i++;
  }

  for(int j = 0;j<i-1;j++){
    printf("%s", args[j]);
  }
}
```

If my understanding of seg faults are correct, this is happening because I am trying to access some sort of memory that this process doesn't have permission to access, but I am unsure why. Anything helps!

EDIT: I have tried to experiment with this a little bit, and had assumed that there wasn't a null terminator at the end of my string, however when I added the line

```
strncat(cur,"\0",50);
```

to the inside of my while loop, just before I assign to args[i] the same result is yielded.

EDIT: updated strtok_r usage

Comment: `char **args=NULL` ... `args[i]=curr;`.  You never allocated any space for args.

Comment: How would I know how much space to allocate, if my input can be of variable length?

Comment: If the input string has length N, there can be at most N/2 tokens.

Comment: @backwardforward Any way that you want. There are lots of options. You can guess and re-allocate more if needed. You can allocate more than you will ever need and "right size" afterwards. There are lots of other ways too.

Comment: Also notice that you call `strtok_r` incorrectly. Only the first call shall pass `temp`. All following calls shall pass `NULL`

Comment: Are you calling `parseCommand` on a string which is writable?  For instance, string literals are not, so `parseCommand("foo bar baz")` would likely crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems:

1. No memory assigned to `args`
2. Wrong use of `strtok_r`

To solve the first problem you can use `realloc` when new tokens are found.

To solve the second problem, you need to call `strtok_r` once using `str` and then `NULL` the rest of the time.

Something like:

```
void parseCommand(char *str)
{
  char *curr;
  char **args=NULL;
  char *saveptr;  

  int i = 0;

  // Look for first token, i.e. pass str
  curr = strtok_r(str, " ", &saveptr);
  
  while(curr != NULL){
    // Allocate memory for the pointer
    char **p = realloc(args, (i + 1) * sizeof *p);
    if (p == NULL) exit(1);
    args = p;

    // Save the pointer
    args[i]=curr;
    i++;

    // Look for next token, i.e. pass NULL
    curr = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &saveptr);
  }

  for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
    printf("%s\n", args[j]);
  }
}
```

When you call the function do:

```
char some_text[] = "Hello how are you";
parseCommand(some_text);
```

**Do not call like**

```
parseCommand("Hello how are you");  // Illegal
```

`strtok_r` will modify the passed string so you must pass it a string that can be modified.